# Can't write the right request in spring-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm working with spring-boot , and having these 3 entites :

*Entity AppUser*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;
    private Long tel;
    private String cin;
    private String email ;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser" )
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="appuser-contrat")
    private Collection<Contrat> contrats = new ArrayList<Contrat>();



    public void addToContrats(Contrat contrat){
        this.contrats.add(contrat);
    }


}
```

*Entity Contrat*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contrat implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        private Date dateDebut ;
        private Date dateFin ;
        private Long idDevloppeur;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_Project")
        @JsonBackReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id_AppUser")
        @JsonBackReference(value="appuser-contrat")
        private AppUser appUser;


}
```

*Entity Project*

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Project implements Serializable{

        @Id @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String intitule;
        private String description;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project" )
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        @JsonManagedReference(value="projet-contrat")
        private Collection<Contrat> contrats  = new ArrayList<Contrat>();



        public void addToContrats(Contrat contrat){
                this.contrats.add(contrat);
        }



 }
```

this is the mapping i'm using :

-One_to_many between AppUser and Contrat .

-One_to_many between Project and Contrat .

So Contrat is in the middle between AppUser and Project .

I'm trying in a repository to write a request to get a List of AppUser who don't have a specified project .

I tried this

```
@Query("select u from AppUser u inner join u.roles r inner join u.contrats c where r = :role and c.appUser not in (" +
            "select d.appUser from Contrat d where d.project = :project )")
```

So i want to get list of users who don't have this project ':project '

but i'm getting an empty list , while i should get the list of all AppUsers as in my application there is no project for any appuser yet .

Any idea how to write this request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm assuming this is `spring-data-jpa` with `Hibernate` as the underlying impl.

My HQL is a little rusty, but something like this should work:

```
select u from AppUser u inner join u.roles r inner join u.contrats c where r = :role and not exists ( from c.project p where p != :project)
```

Here's a good article: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/03/09/power-of-hql-condition-on-a-collection/

Comment: Thank you for this answer and also the explanation in the article ! :)